# Java Observer pattern not calling update function

Tags: java, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

I have a problem trying to implement the Observer-pattern into my MVC solution for a simple program, however I can't get the observer to notify "update" like it should.

These are the relevant parts of the code, there is a third class(Controller) which calls the "spelarNamn" function.
I have tested the "spelarNamn" function and I know the program enters it, the only problem is that it never enters update function in View.

```
public class Model extends Observable {
    private String titel;
    
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Model model = new Model();
        Controller controller = new Controller(model);
        View view = new View(model, controller);
        model.addObserver(view);
    }
    
    public void spelarNamn(String s1, String s2){
        titel = s1 + " VS " + s2;
        this.setChanged();
        this.notifyObservers();
    }
}

public class View implements Observer {
    public void update(Observable o, Object x){
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call spelarNamn() function ?

Comment: If im not misstaken those 2 are part of the Observer pattern that is included in Java? I didn't create those methods by myself.

Comment: spelarNamn() is called through another class, alltho I know for sure that the spelarNamn() function is initiated(I have done system out prints in it to check etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller is calling the spelarNamn() method before the Observer is added. Move model.addObserver(view) up before the controller call.

Comment: The case was actually that I started my program through the View constructor, so that i ran View before I even added the observer, your answer made me see that. Thanks alot!